# Make django query from database based on two models

Tags: python, sql, django, django-forms, django-queryset

I am working on search page in which doctor can search for patient with `name` ,`start_date` and `end_date`. Here start_date and end_date are the date range in which any document was uploaded. The result should return all the patients whose name is `name` and has documents uploaded between `start_date` and `end_date`.

```py
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(to=Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'document', 'patient')

    # many document can have same patient

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.name}'
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.name}'
```

```py
class Patient(models.Model):
    # required fields
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=False, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    
    # not required fields
    address = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_zip = models.IntegerField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=17, blank=True, null=True) # mobile
    alternate_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=17, blank=True, null=True) # alternate

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

I can get all documents uploaded between particular dates like this

```py
documents  = Document.objects.filter(
                    uploaded_at__gte=start_date
                ).intersection(
                    Document.objects.filter(uploaded_at__lte=end_date)
                )
```

but I cant figure out a way to combine above result with this

```
query = Patient.objects.filter(
                    Q(first_name__icontains=search_key)         |
                    Q(last_name__icontains=search_key)          |   
                    Q(email__icontains=search_key)              |
                    Q(city__icontains=search_key)               |
                    Q(phone_number__icontains=search_key)       |
                    Q(alternate_number__icontains=search_key)   |
                    Q(country__icontains=search_key)           
    
                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double underscores to look through a relation, so here we can filter on `Patient`s which have a document in the given range:

```
# Patients which match the search_key, and have
# documents uploaded in the (start_date, end_date) range

query = Patient.objects.filter(
    Q(first_name__icontains=search_key) |
    Q(last_name__icontains=search_key) |
    Q(email__icontains=search_key) |
    Q(city__icontains=search_key) |
    Q(phone_number__icontains=search_key) |
    Q(alternate_number__icontains=search_key) |
    Q(country__icontains=search_key),
    document__uploaded_at__range=(start_date, end_date)
).distinct()
```

The `.distinct()` here prevents, as you commented, that you retrieve the same patient multiple times (once per `Document` in the range).

or `Document`s that have a `Patient` that matches the given conditions:

```
# Documents uploaded in the (start_date, end_date) range
# which match a Patient with the search_key.

query = Document.objects.filter(
    Q(patient__first_name__icontains=search_key) |
    Q(patient__last_name__icontains=search_key) |
    Q(patient__email__icontains=search_key) |
    Q(patient__city__icontains=search_key) |
    Q(patient__phone_number__icontains=search_key) |
    Q(patient__alternate_number__icontains=search_key) |
    Q(patient__country__icontains=search_key),
    uploaded_at__range=(start_date, end_date)
)
```

Comment: This approach does work but needs little modification. If you notice there could be multiple `document` associated single `patient`. So when I am using this ` uploaded_at__range=(start_date, end_date)`  I am getting multiple instances of the same patient in queryset. To answer this may use `distinct()` method? Right now when I run this I get following output `In [16]: Patient.objects.filter(document__uploaded_at__range=[start_date, end_date])                                                             
Out[16]: <QuerySet [Aman Goyal, Aman Goyal, patient lname, patient lname, Aman Goyal]>`

Comment: @amangoyal: yes you can indeed add a `.distinct()` at the end.

Comment: Just for the future reference and searchers. Could you update this in the answer? I believe this is important.

Comment: @amangoyal: I've updated it with a `.distinct()` at the end (and explaining why it is useful) :)